# CSRF token creation and Content-Security-Policy header

Tags: javascript, security, csrf

I've just updated my site with setting my Content-Security-Policy Header and after fixing the slew of errors which popped up in the console, I am now down to one.

The relevant part of my .htaccess file is `script-src 'self'`. Here I do not set `'unsafe-inline'` as that kind of goes against the point of setting the CSP in the first place - at least in my reading.

With Craft setting a CSRF token and my site doing POST requests over AJAX, I set the token name and value as recommended here: https://craftcms.com/support/csrf-protection - which is inline and above in my CSP I do not allow inline scripts. So as you can see it falls apart and Craft spits out a 400 error.

Is there any way I can get around this? I'd like to keep my CSP and with CSRF being enabled by default in Craft 3, I'd like this ironed out before then.

Comment: While my question still stands, I have had to can my CSP due to the incompatibility I was facing with CSRF. If anyone can provide some insight around this I would be forever grateful.